# Block vertical scroll while using SlidingListTile

Tags: gluon

I would like to use the SlidingListTile, but I am having some issues.
I think that when we use the horizontal sliding the vertical scroll should be locked, because is getting hard to complete de slide on the phone.

Did someone get a situation like that?

Thanks in advance,

Here is part of my code:

```
    slidingTile.swipedLeftProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv && edit != null) {
            edit.accept(currentItem);
        }
        slidingTile.resetTilePosition();
    });
    slidingTile.swipedRightProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv && edit != null) {
            edit.accept(currentItem);
        }
        slidingTile.resetTilePosition();
    });
```

Comment: Are you referring to this `SlidingListTile` [implementation](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/comments2.0/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/comments20/views/SlidingListTile.java)? That already includes checks for scroll or sliding events.

Comment: Yes, but it is not working, when we slide the finger, the vertical scroll mess up the horizontal sliding, not completing the process.

Comment: It works fine for me. Which is your Android device? There is a scroll lock set [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/comments2.0/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/comments20/views/CommentsPresenter.java#L139).

Comment: It does not work fine neither Android or IOS.

Comment: Do you have many comments? I see now that if you have 10+ comments when sliding you can still scroll.

Comment: Yes, I am using in a listView with dozens of records.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look. Probably some scrolling events are still not consumed.

Comment: Got here, it was missing this code you sent me, I added in ListCell class and made a little change and it is working now! Thank you for your help! 

// block scrolling when sliding
        listView.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, e -> {
            if (slidingTile.slidingProperty().get() && e.getDeltaY() != 0) {
                e.consume();
            }
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there is an error in the Comments 2.0 [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/comments2.0).

The `CommentsPresenter` defines a custom `ListCell` for the `ListView`, and creates a [binding](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/a5c9e655cd809053f96b218eaba2d1c5272f5261/comments2.0/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/comments20/views/CommentsPresenter.java#L117) from a single `BooleanProperty` to each of the cells in the list view:

```
commentsList.setCellFactory(cell -> { 
        final CommentListCell commentListCell = new CommentListCell(
                service,...);

        // notify view that cell is sliding
        sliding.bind(commentListCell.slidingProperty());

        return commentListCell; 
    });
```

Obviously, the sliding property of each cell may vary in time, but only the last one set will prevail, so it won't reflect the change of this property for any of the rest of the cells.

The fix is easy: don't use bindings, but a listener *for each cell* that will set the value when that cell is sliding:

```
commentsList.setCellFactory(cell -> { 
        final CommentListCell commentListCell = new CommentListCell(
                service,...);

        // notify view that cell is sliding
        commentListCell.slidingProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> 
            sliding.set(nv));

        return commentListCell; 
    });
```

I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/issues/13).